# CallerMemberNameAttribute and Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

Does Roslyn CTP support `CallerMemberNameAttribute` and others similar?

I have a method with several parameters, some obligatory, and also there is a parameter with default value, marked with `CallerMemberName` attribute.

I am generating a call of this method by Roslyn, passing only obligatory parameters, and expecting it to generate values for compiler-generated parameters too, but this does not happen, they have default values.

Is this a limitation of Roslyn's current version, or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [What's New in the Microsoft "Roslyn" September 2012 CTP](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5a56122b-d6e5-40e0-8912-60eba3fc9a01/whats-new-in-the-microsoft-roslyn-september-2012-ctp), it is noted that:

> **The full C# 4 and Visual Basic 10** languages are supported by the
>   parser, but there are several language features that are not yet
>   completely implemented in the current Roslyn compilers.

The [Caller Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) feature is introduced in .NET Framework 4.5 (C# 5.0 and Visual Basic 11). Therefore, Roslyn does not support it in the current version. However obtaining caller information could be accomplished using something like the following code snippet from "[Can I get function caller/callee information from Roslyn?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85a816cb-e931-4b49-893a-abbbf38c7a38/can-i-get-function-callercallee-information-from-roslyn)" question asked in MSDN forums:

```
var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(code);

var semanticModel = Compilation.Create("compilation")
    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree)
    .AddReferences(new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
    .GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

var baz = syntaxTree.Root
    .DescendentNodes()
    .OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>()
    .Single(m => m.Identifier.ValueText == "C1")
    .ChildNodes()
    .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
    .Single(m => m.Identifier.ValueText == "Baz");

var bazSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(baz);

var invocations = syntaxTree.Root
    .DescendentNodes()
    .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();

var bazInvocations = invocations
    .Where(i => semanticModel.GetSemanticInfo(i).Symbol == bazSymbol);
```